# Have to add different ole documents in doc file like pdf,ppt,etc is there any open source solution?

Tags: apache, apache-poi

I have a scenario where i need to add multiple files like pdf,ppt,excel,etc in a doc file.We have tried using Apache POI but couldn't achieve it.
Is there any open source API to do it? Appreciate the response.